# case like does not work in Splunk, no string is matched

Tags: splunk

I have a simple table:

[image]

Now I need to add a tag according to the Hostname:

```
index=log_ad 
| eval tag=case(Hostname like '%SRV%', 'server', Hostname like '%DC%', 'controller', 1=1, "not matched") 
| top tag, Hostname
```

But all tag are "not matched", what's wrong?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, `like` is a [function](https://docs.splunk.com/Documentation/Splunk/9.0.5/SearchReference/ConditionalFunctions#like.28.26lt.3Bstr.26gt.3B.2C.26lt.3Bpattern.26gt.3B.29) - so it needs to be used as one

This *should* work:

```
index=log_ad 
| eval tag=case(like(Hostname,"%SRV%"), "server", like(Hostname,"%DC%"), "controller", 1=1, "not matched") 
| top tag, Hostname
```

Comment: Interesting, why won't splunk report an syntax error on my query?

Comment: @daisy ... because it's *not*, strictly-speaking, a "syntax error". What you passed to the `case` function was "valid" (albeit not at all what you *expected*) SPL. Splunk cannot know what you *meant* to tell it - only what you tell it. So long as you don't tell it something syntactically incorrect, it will try to run it.